# Loop over object es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object which looks like this:

```
const object = {
head: 1,
eyes: 2,
arms: 2,
legs: 3
}
```

I want to loop over this object and this and log out each key name e.g. `eyes` for the amount of the value.

this would result in:

```
head
eyes
eyes
arms
arms 
legs 
legs
legs
```

Currently I have this solution but it feels like it could be done more neatly and readible.

```
Object.keys(object)
  .map(key => {
    return [...Array(object[key])].map( (_, i) => {
      return console.log(key)
   })
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Object.entries()` and `map()` method and return new array.

```js
const object = {head: 1,eyes: 2,arms: 2,legs: 3}

const res = [].concat(...Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => Array(v).fill(k)))
console.log(res)
```

Or you could use `reduce()` with spread syntax in array.

```js
const object = {head: 1,eyes: 2,arms: 2,legs: 3}

const res = Object
  .entries(object)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => [...r, ...Array(v).fill(k)], [])
  // Or you can use push instead
  // .reduce((r, [k, v]) => (r.push(...Array(v).fill(k)), r), [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Object.entries(object)
  .forEach(([key, times]) => console.log((key + "\n").repeat(times)));
```

One may use `String.prototype.repeat`...

Comment: Why not just put it in a built-in snippet if you want to show how it works?

Answer (score 2):

> *"...it feels like it could be done more neatly and readible."*

Recursion makes it pretty clean and understandable.

```js
const object = {
  head: 1,
  eyes: 2,
  arms: 2,
  legs: 3
};

Object.entries(object).forEach(function f([k,v]) {
  if (v) {
    console.log(k);
    f([k, --v]);
  }
})
```

---

You can rearrange things a bit if you know the value will always be greater than `0`.

```js
const object = {
  head: 1,
  eyes: 2,
  arms: 2,
  legs: 3
};

Object.entries(object).forEach(function f([k,v]) {
  console.log(k);
  if (--v) f([k, v]);
})
```

Comment: While this is not much cleaner, its at least creative ;)